# Opening Chrome Console Blocks Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I am making a Chrome Extension which works fine. As soon as I open up the console (right click, inspect element) it blocks any javascript? Is this some new feature of chrome - and if not, how do I get rid of it! I tried even inspecting element on a google chrome local page like chrome// whatever.. still the same problem. First image is what shows on the page, second image is what I see when I click Manage Javascript Blocking.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I don't think this was obvious anywhere so for anyone in future... It was a setting in the console - I don't know how I turned it on because I've never seen them but there we go!

Open Console > Settings > Disable Javascript